# NServiceBus exception and subscriber not able to read queue

Tags: c#, nservicebus, ravendb

I've been battling with this for a few days now with no luck. I've setup a NServiceBus project by following the guidelines on the getting started guide.
My MVC site successfully pushed messages onto my queue, but the subscriber never reads them off. No error messages until after about a minute, where the following pops up on the console:

2012-06-26 13:05:43,648 [1] FATAL NServiceBus.Hosting.GenericHost [(null)] <(null)> - Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Raven.Client.IDocumentStore)' on type 'RavenTimeoutPersistence'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadStringInternal(Func`1 getRespo
nse)
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseString()
   at Raven.Client.Connection.HttpJsonRequest.ReadResponseJson()

I can successfully connect to Raven via the web portal, and I can see my queues listed there - so am at a loss as to why NServiceBus cannot read the messages on the queue. I've reinstalled MSMQ, rebooted machine, re-installed NServiceBus - nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea as to whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be another victim of Kaspersky Anti Virus. Even though firewall was set to "Allow all network connections", turning it off solved the issue.